# Server database problem

Tags: database, server

> i just transferred my website from
>   shared server to VPS, but then it is
>   not starting, when i inquired with the
>   VPS technical support then they
>   emailed me something this, which i am
>   not understanding:- email
>
> > Your site "www.onlinemba.co.in" has
> >     been migrated from your previous host
> >     and we are now getting a blank page
> >     while accessing the database dependant
> >     php files. There seems to be an issue
> >     with the database codings as all other
> >     php files are accessing fine and there
> >     is also no problem with the database
> >     connectivity. You can check for the
> >     same by accessing the site preview URL
> >     "http://38.100.101.228/info.php".
> >
> > Your Kloxo panel details are
> >
> > URL : XXXXX User : XXXXXX pass : XXXXX
> >
> > Server root access detail are as
> >     follows
> >
> > IP : 38.100.101.228 User : XXXXXXX
> >     Pass : XXXXXXX
> >
> > Kindly check your database once with
> >     your database developers with the
> >     details given above and let us know
> >     for further help.
>
> what should i do?

ok well i did some changes for this in wp-config.php,
but after that the admin guys from hosting are saying me this:

> Virtual host entry for the IP is
>   pointing to different folder ( which
>   doesn't have any contents ), hence you
>   have received the default page. I have
>   pointed in to the correct folder
>   "onlinemb". You can view the blank
>   page, please check and resolve it.

i edited the database MySql hostname from local host, to the IP-38.100.101.228
but then he changed again to local host, and again the blank page came, what to do now?

Comment: I think you should really sort this out with hosting support. If you don't understand their instructions tell them that and ask to explain more clearly or in more detailed way (support is their job after all).

Comment: they are totally blank with this problem, they say to download the wordpress from the ftp and check it in local host

Comment: i made it work, i renamed the plugins folder name to plugin_temp, and website started, there is a problem in some of the plugins,
thanks i cracked it out myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Rarst is right.  It sounds like you need to configure the wp-config.php file for the new database.  Just go to the cpanel or other control panel of your hosting service, and use the address they use for the host address.  If the database is on the same server as the web site, localhost is used.

I am not sure how you moved you website.  I assume that it is a WordPress site, and it is not difficult to move.  When I did this, I made a new installation of WordPress on the new hosting service.  This included installing WordPress with a new database.

Then, I went to the old site WordPress dashboard, found the Export menu, and saved the resulting XML file.  This file contains all the database info for your site.

At the new site, I simply went to the new site dashboard Import menu and imported the file from the old site.  The new database system then had the correct data from the old site.  There were a few issues on the new site, mainly dealing with cosmetic things.

As a matter of fact we should all keep a current backup of our WordPress database, and there is a plugin for that.

Answer (score 2):

Had you configured database settings in `wp-config.php` for the new server?

Hosting provider says your site has issues accessing database. Assuming they confirmed database is working as expected it leaves site configuration itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the wp-config.php file, try replacing the (localhost) with the IP address you shared above